# Why when this code prompting me to input again and then when I just press enter without typing anything, the function number gets called?

Tags: python-3.x

when tryAgain is executed without typing anything and then press enter or typing random words and numbers, the number function gets called bypassing the if statement. why is that?

```
def number():
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number! ")
        x = int(num)
        print("You input {} which is a number".format(num))
    except ValueError:
        print("{} is not a number!".format(num))

    tryAgain = input("Want to try again?[Y/N] ") #this one right here
    if tryAgain.lower() != 'n':
        number()



number()
```

Comment: Because `'' != 'n'`.

Comment: yuri should be right, but you can prove it by logging the value of tryAgain.

Comment: lol :D tnx for helping a noob like me!